# D3 only rendering SVG chart when going back or forward to the page

Tags: javascript, html, django, d3.js, svg

On my local, D3 only renders the svg chart when going back to or forward to the page. It doesn't render on initial page load.

Following the D3 [tutorial here](https://scrimba.com/p/pb4WsX/cwmGZCw) I can get the chart to render perfectly in [a codepen](https://codepen.io/ryan-britnell/pen/MRQvMB) or when going back to the page.

I'm running the page using Django's flatpages app. I've tried multiple browsers and dev tools. The page returns no errors and the data is loaded before the function to create the chart is called.

Is there a way to debug D3 or the Javascript function that I am missing?

I suspect it's something to do with async and I need to add a window.onload like below but so far this hasn't worked.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    fetch(api)
        .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
        .then(function(data) {
            var parsedData = parseData(data);
            window.onload = function() {
                drawChart(parsedData);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) { console.log(err); })
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the bug was unrelated, it wasn't an async issue. Fontawesome was adding an svg earlier in the page which was then causing issues with my JavaScript chart drawing function. To fix I had to change what d3 was selecting from 'svg' to a specific class.